# How to bundle exe file into a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I created a google chrome extension that uses native messaging host (NMH). That extension includes three parts:

1. .js file, handles url and sends it to NMH
2. NMH, exe file that handles url message and does other stuff
3. Installer, exe file that adds extension info to user registry; copies manifest and NMH app to user machine

How can I bundle my installer to chrome extension? During packing, exe files are not accepted as a part of crx file?

Answer (score 1):

its not possible. you should instead distribute the installer which could install the extension, or have the extension download the exe and ask users to run it (thou I doubt  chrome will let you run the exe after download)

Comment: Thanks. And how to achieve by second way? Is there any example?

Comment: ive created files (in Chrome Downloads folder) in chrome extensions before, google some more (try the method that uses document.createEvent('MouseEvents') on a created "a" element with a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), Ive done it from the background page, adding the "a" on the background page. Show us attempts and specific issues. However like I said, I didnt do it for ".exe" file types, which Chrome might block or display a scary warning as it should.

Comment: I tried with exe and it works. But how to trigger it after extension installation? I mean when user adds extension to chrome, how to make this download start automatically?

Comment: you cant. you must instruct the user to do so.

Comment: Only what I want is to download exe automatically once extension added to Chrome. Afterward, user will run that exe manually. There are several chrome extensions in the store, that download exe to user machine. But when I do it, It gave "Failed-Network Error". I do not know why? Chrome did not trust my exe.